# Unable to open a pop-up div on button's click that is in side the GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and a button inside it. What I want to do is to reference a simple pop-up div from [this link](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorials/demos/Popup_Dialog_Windows_using_JQuery.aspx). I want to open it on button click.

Here is my HTML Code:

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="gvContactUs" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        DataKeyNames="ContactID" Width="100%" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" OnPageIndexChanging="gvContactUs_PageIndexChanging"
                        OnRowCommand="gvContactUs_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvContactUs_RowDataBound"
                        OnRowDeleting="gvContactUs_RowDeleting" OnSorting="gvContactUs_Sorting" AllowPaging="True"
                        BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" GridLines="None">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="3%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button Text="text" ID="hello" runat="server" />
                                    <div>
                                        <div id="overlay" class="web_dialog_overlay">
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="dialog" class="web_dialog">
                                            <table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="web_dialog_title">
                                                        Message
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="web_dialog_title align_right">
                                                        <a href="#" id="btnClose">Close</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 15px;">
                                                        <div id="brands">
                                                            <%#Eval("Message")%></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                                                        <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="7%" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("Name")%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <HeaderStyle Width="11%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="13%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <a href="mailto:<%#Eval("Email")%>" class="EmailLink">
                                        <%#Eval("Email")%></a>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="13%" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="7%">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("Phone")%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="8%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="7%">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("Subject")%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="13%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="7%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ContactID") %>' runat="server"
                                        ID="lnkbtnDelete"><img src="Images/delete.gif" border="0" alt='Click to Delete this Entry' title='Click to Delete this Entry' />
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="7%" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <HeaderStyle Height="30px" BackColor="#3E3050" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
                        <PagerStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#C6C3C6" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <RowStyle Height="25px" BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the Css used for Pop Up

```css
.web_dialog_overlay
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000000;
    opacity: .15;
    filter: alpha(opacity=15);
    -moz-opacity: .15;
    z-index: 101;
    display: none;
}
.web_dialog
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 380px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -190px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid #336699;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 102;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.web_dialog_title
{
    border-bottom: solid 2px #336699;
    background-color: #336699;
    padding: 4px;
    color: White;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.web_dialog_title a
{
    color: White;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.align_right
{
    text-align: right;
}
```

And here is the jQuery code for pop up:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {
    $('input[id*=hello]').click(function () {
        ShowDialog(true);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});


$('[id$=btnShowModal]').live('click', function (e) {
    ShowDialog(true);
    e.preventDefault();

});

$("#btnClose").click(function (e) {
    HideDialog();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
    var brand = $("#brands input:radio:checked").val();
    $("#output").html("<b>Your favorite mobile brand: </b>" + brand);
    HideDialog();
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
function ShowDialog(modal) {
    $("#overlay").show();
    $("#dialog").fadeIn(300);
    if (modal) {
        $("#overlay").unbind("click");
    } else {
        $("#overlay").click(function (e) {
            HideDialog();
        });
    }
}

function HideDialog() {
    $("#overlay").hide();
    $("#dialog").fadeOut(300);
}
```

Comment: why down votes??????have i asked something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a silly mistake :

```
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvContactUs" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        DataKeyNames="ContactID" Width="100%" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="1" OnPageIndexChanging="gvContactUs_PageIndexChanging"
                        OnRowCommand="gvContactUs_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="gvContactUs_RowDataBound"
                        OnRowDeleting="gvContactUs_RowDeleting" OnSorting="gvContactUs_Sorting" AllowPaging="True"
                        BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" GridLines="None">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="3%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button Text="text" ID="hello" runat="server" />
                                    <div>
                                        <div id="overlay" class="web_dialog_overlay">
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="dialog" class="web_dialog">
                                            <table style="width: 100%; border: 0px;" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="web_dialog_title">
                                                        Message
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td class="web_dialog_title align_right">
                                                        <a href="#" id="btnClose">Close</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 15px;">
                                                        <div id="brands">
                                                            <%#Eval("Message")%></a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">
                                                        <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    **</div>**
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="7%" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("Name")%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                <HeaderStyle Width="11%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="13%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <a href="mailto:<%#Eval("Email")%>" class="EmailLink">
                                        <%#Eval("Email")%></a>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="13%" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="7%">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("Phone")%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="8%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" HeaderStyle-Width="7%">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="40px" />
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%#Eval("Subject")%>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="13%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="7%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ContactID") %>' runat="server"
                                        ID="lnkbtnDelete"><img src="Images/delete.gif" border="0" alt='Click to Delete this Entry' title='Click to Delete this Entry' />
                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle Width="7%" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <HeaderStyle Height="30px" BackColor="#3E3050" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
                        <PagerStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#C6C3C6" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <RowStyle Height="25px" BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Forgot to close a div and in jquery code there is a small mistake that is :

```
 $(function () {
    $('input[id*=hello]').click(function (**e**) {
        ShowDialog(true);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

**e** was missed.  by the way thanks all............. :)